# WTFforms: how to avoid the OverflowError in NumberRange validator for large integers?

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, integer-overflow

I am writing a **Flask** web application and I am using **WTForms** for the forms.
One of the inputs is an IntegerField

```
field = IntegerField('Field', validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=100)])
```

Since I am using a the validator `NumberRange(min=0, max=100)` I correctly get refused an input like `10090` but when it comes to inserting inputs that are way too large, for example:

```
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something `wtforms` doesn't handle, so you would have to:

```
try:
    field = IntegerField('Field', validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=100)])
except OverflowError as e:
    raise Exception(e.args[0]) # Or better yet - use the actuall exception thrown when the input is 101
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! How would I write the error handler in such a way that also this input is invalid? I would like the same exact behavior of inserting `10090` as input

Comment: I don't actually remember the Exception by thrown`wtforms` when inserting bad input, but you basically just import that exception, and raise it after the exception is caught (I edited my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: I tried to insert your code in the field declaration inside the form class but I still get the same error :(